# Split image into multiple grids

Tags: python, opencv

im using the following code to split the image into 20 equal parts of grid

```
import cv2

im =  cv2.imread("apple.jpg")
im = cv2.resize(im,(1000,500))
imgwidth=im.shape[0]
imgheight=im.shape[1]


y1 = 0
M = imgwidth//20
N = imgheight//20

for x in range(0,imgwidth,M):
    for y in range(0, imgheight, N):
        x1 = x + M
        y1 = y + N
        tiles = im[x:x+M,y:y+N]

        print(y1)
        cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x1, y1), (0, 255, 0))
        cv2.imwrite("save/" + str(y)+".png",tiles)

cv2.imwrite("asas.png",im)
```

However i have two issues,

1. The saved images are not of proper uniform size
2. It only draws grid upon half of the image and not entirely.

How can I be able to sort this out?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a bit of confusion which I guess is caused by how `numpy` handles image dimensions and coordinates using the `(row, column)` convention and how OpenCV handles them using `(x, y)` convention.

The `shape` member of `numpy` array contains image height at first index and width at second index.

A usual convention used for the naming convention is that `M` is the number of rows or height of the image while `N` is the number of columns or width of the image.

Another problem is that not all the sub-images are being saved because names are assigned using `y` variable only which eventually overwrites the existing images due to repetition of `y`. Unique names are required for saving all the sub-images. One possible way is to use both `x` and `y` to generate a unique name.

Following is a working code with all of the above-mentioned issues fixed.

```
import cv2

im =  cv2.imread("apple.jpg")
im = cv2.resize(im,(1000,500))

imgheight=im.shape[0]
imgwidth=im.shape[1]

y1 = 0
M = imgheight//20
N = imgwidth//20

for y in range(0,imgheight,M):
    for x in range(0, imgwidth, N):
        y1 = y + M
        x1 = x + N
        tiles = im[y:y+M,x:x+N]

        cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x1, y1), (0, 255, 0))
        cv2.imwrite("save/" + str(x) + '_' + str(y)+".png",tiles)

cv2.imwrite("asas.png",im)
```