# How to measure an monochrome area with unit squares made from a custom gridline?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, grid, units-of-measurement

I have an image with gridline like this and I want to measure each monochrome area with unit squares made from that gridline. The squares that mix with different colours shall not be counted. In the image there are 3 colors: yellow, orange and blue. Borders and gridlines does not count. The original images don't have gridlines.

[Full Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OKN8.jpg)

[image: !Image here, I'll fix this when I have 10 reputation]
[image: closeup]

So far I can [count the number of black and white pixels in the image](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/opencv-counting-the-number-of-black-and-white-pixels-in-the-image/) but I don't know how to customize the code to suit my needs.

Comment: monochrome means "no color" (or one hue, shades of it). what do you mean?

Comment: sounds like you want to downsample that source image (ignoring the grid), while maintaining the color palette, or applying a palette/posterization effect?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz so for example, in the image there are 3 colors: yellow, orange and blue. Borders and gridlines does not count. We also have original images that don't have gridlines. Does that answer you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use np.unique to count the occurance of all colors in the img:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
  
# reading the image data from desired directory
img = cv2.imread("1OKN8m.jpg")
cv2.imshow('Image',img)

img_1d = img.reshape(img.shape[0]*img.shape[1], img.shape[2])
unique_colors, counts = np.unique(img_1d, axis=0, return_counts=True)
print(f'Unique colors: {unique_colors}')
print(f'Counts: {counts}')
```

because it is a jpeg, the "monochrome" areas contain a lot of different colors, so you should select all the unique colors that are close enough according to you and count up their individual counts.

Comment: it seems like this only count via the pixels? Is there a way to count via the squares made from the gridline?

Comment: `print(img.shape[0]*img.shape[1], img_1d.size)` returns `4584300 13752900`. `print(unique_colors.size, counts.size)` returns `481008 160336`.  Shouldn't the numbers in each pair be the same?

Comment: `size` seems to count the total number of element, not the size of the first dimension, the numbers are 3x for this rgb image.

Comment: To count the squares you could downsize the image, but you have to count the size of the gridline, I estimated 85 byt 115:
`
img = cv2.resize(img, (85, 115), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
`

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to go is to [split image into multiple grids](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49397941/3416774), then check individual parts if they are monochrome or not.